# Asymptotic Distribution & Probability Limit

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I am trying to solve this question:

Derive the probability limit and asymptotic distribution of the squared standardized sample
average.

I do know that standardized RV has mean 0 and variance 1 and thus by using Chebyshev's inequality we can find the probability limit. However, I confused as to what does it mean by "squared standardized sample average." If someone can explain that, I'll be grateful.

Comment: Probably, it is $(\bar{X}_n-\mathsf{E}\bar{X}_n)^2/\operatorname{Var}(\bar{X}_n)$.

Comment: @d.k.o. thank you for your reply. It was really helpful in solving the problem.

Derive the probability limit and the asymptotic distribution (with appropriate standardization) of the sample average of squared RVs.
Can you please help me with this?

Comment: In the second question, I have applied Central Limit Theorem to just say that asymptotic distribution will be simply the normal distribution where our random variable will be Y=$\bar{X^{2}}$. What do you think about it?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_method#Second-order_delta_method